# Access webapp that uses websockets

Tags: websocket, atmosphere

I'm totally new to the websocket world. I'm using Atmosphere to implement websockets in my Angular webapp and I have only been able to create a partial solution. When a user focuses on an input text element the others users see that input is disabled, and when the user's focus leaves the input text element the other users see the new content.

But what if one user accessed the webapp and another one was already focused on the input text element. How can I detect this? Is still possible with atmosphere/websocket or I need to implement another kind of strategy?

Comment: I guess you would need to store the state of whether the input text is locked on the server. Each client can read the state of the 'lock' to see if they can edit the text. You'll need to think about a timeout of inactivity as well, in-case one client has entered the input text but remains inactive.

Comment: Good idea but what is the best method to achieve this store and read operation?

Comment: And about the inactivity. If I close the connection after a period of inactivity I suppose I'll lost all modification updates made by the other users.

Comment: You might want to track which connection is currently locking the text field, if a connection that has currently locked the text field dies, then you can release the lock for other connections to edit the text field.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that when I enter the app I don't know which fileds I need to disable because I have no trace of the messages previously shared by the other users. I can think that when I enter the app and the connection is established I can push a message and the other clients that get that messages reply by repushing the previous locking message but there must be a smarter way.

Comment: When the app connects to the server initially, can you not just get the current state of the necessary fields, and from then on listen for updates?

Comment: Sure but then where and with what I store that information?

Comment: Store the information on the server in memory